# How to plot a DE equation?

Tags: python

I need to plot the DE equation, but I have no idea how to do that.

First, solve the problem.

```
#10527113
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Solve the DE: 3y'' + 2y' +y = 0
x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y', cls=Function)
diffeq1 = Eq(3*y(x).diff(x,x) + 2*y(x).diff(x) + y(x), 0)
ans1 = dsolve ( diffeq1, y(x) )
print ( ans1 )
```

Then the plotting part.

```
#plotting
#Let x : [0, 2*pi], c1 = 1 and c2 = 0
b = []
a = np.linspace( 0, 2*np.pi )
for k in a:
    b.append(ans1.subs(x, k))

plt.plot(a, b, label="curve")
```

I got a right 'ans1' in my code, but I can't plot it successfully.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

When you plot, you said in comments that c1 = 1 and c2 = 0 but you did not set it in your DE solution ans1. I added the substitution in your code as well as selecting the evaluation value of the solution for plotting.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Solve the DE: 3y'' + 2y' +y = 0
from sympy.solvers.ode import classify_sysode

x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y', cls=Function)
diffeq1 = Eq(3*y(x).diff(x,x) + 2*y(x).diff(x) + y(x), 0)
ans1 = dsolve ( diffeq1, y(x) )
print ( ans1 )
# Eq(y(x), (C1*sin(sqrt(2)*x/3) + C2*cos(sqrt(2)*x/3))/exp(x)**(1/3))

print (ans1)

#plotting
# Let x : [0, 2*pi], c1 = 1 and c2 = 0
c1 = symbols('C1')
c2 = symbols('C2')
ans1 = ans1.subs(c1, 1) # substitute for c1
ans1 = ans1.subs(c2, 0) # substitute for c2
b = []
a = np.linspace( 0, 2*np.pi )
for k in a:
    sol = ans1.subs(x, k)
    b.append(sol.rhs) # select the value for plotting

plt.plot(a, b, label="curve")
plt.show()
```